# Which words can describe people who know mediocre level on everything

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking an adjective which can be used to describe people who know a bit of everything , somebody who is not superficial in term of general information irrespective of someone's age.

I'd rather not  use the word *intellectual* because it depicts an academic or philosopher who is very good at the area they the work area in my mind.Can we call a college guy as intellectual just because he reads a lot and knows pretty much something on everything?

I'd rather not  use the word *well-rounded* because it includes someone's sportive activities but I am asking more about knowledge.

Maybe a word which can be used by someone  to describe themselves who dare to attend " who wants to be millionaire" contest ?

Comment: Perhaps "dilettante" or "dabbler"; "trivia master".

Comment: @DanBron - Those are nouns. The OP asks for an adjective.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK "Dilettante-ish"; "dabble-y" ;)

Comment: +1 for "dabbler". Example: "*he was a dabbler, learning the basics of many arts but mastering none*". The adjective *eclectic* partially fits, but it has a positive connotation (definition: interested in ideas, style, or taste from a broad and diverse range of sources).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest **[knowledgeable](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/knowledgeable)**. Cambridge Dictionaries Online

Other possibilities: well-informed, well read, educated, widely-read, erudite.

Comment: +1. Administrivia: I don't think you need to name the dictionary you're linking to unless you're quoting it (but I don't think there's any problem naming it, either).

Answer (score 5):

Not a single word but conveys what OP want to say:

[**Jack of all trades**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_of_all_trades,_master_of_none):

> "Jack of all trades, master of none" is a figure of speech used in reference to a person that is competent with many skills, but spends too much time learning each new skill that **he/she can not become an expert in any particular one**.

Comment: Not an adjective either.

Answer (score 1):

Although they also carry other connotations, these might suffice? 
**Cultured** or **Cultivated**